# Using Local Methods within React Lifecycle Methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was curious to see if the following code would work:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 componentDidMount() {
  logger('mount')
 }
 componentDidUpdate() {
  logger('update')
 }
 logger = x => {
  console.log(x)
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <div className='container'>
    
   </div>
  )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I've been working with React for a while now and never came across a reason to use a local method within a lifecycle method, but I thought I'd try it out today out of curiosity. I haven't been able to find any designated explanation as to  why this might not work. Is it the order in which the app is initialized and it's just not seeing the it when it's called, or is it something basic that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Reading suggestion: [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it may be as simple as changing out `logger('mount')` and `logger('update')` for `this.logger('mount')` and `this.logger('update')` :)

Comment: As I figured, must've been something basic I was missing :p Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend your function calls with `this.` to get access to local methods:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 componentDidMount() {
  this.logger('mount')
 }
 componentDidUpdate() {
  this.logger('update')
 }
 logger = x => {
  console.log(x)
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <div className='container'>
    
   </div>
  )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```